# Python list comprehension with multiple loops

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My goal is to create a one liner to produce a following list:

```
list_100 = ['ch1%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]
list_200 = ['ch2%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]

final_list = list_100 + list_200
[ch101,ch102,ch103,ch104,ch105, ch201,ch202,ch203,ch204,ch205]
```

is there some way to do that in one line:

```
final_list = ['ch%.1d%.2d' % (y for y in range(1,3), x for x in range(1,6)]
```

Comment: What is wrong with `final_list=['ch1%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]+['ch2%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
>>> ['ch%.1d%.2d' % (y, x) for y in range(1,3) for x in range(1,6)]
['ch101',
 'ch102',
 'ch103',
 'ch104',
 'ch105',
 'ch201',
 'ch202',
 'ch203',
 'ch204',
 'ch205']
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
final_list = ['ch{}0{}'.format(x,y) for x in range(1,3) for y in range(1,6)]
```

To address the comment below, you can simply multiply `x` by 10:

```
final_list = ['ch{}{}'.format(x*10,y) for x in range(1,12) for y in range(1,6)]
```

Comment: One concern about this solution is that once the second number goes above 9 it breaks. It is likewise for the other `str.format` based solution.

Comment: You're right, and I noticed that while submitting this, but I took the easy path and just solved what was asked :) - it also wasn't immediately clear to me what the expected behavior would be beyond 9.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid python:

```
final_list = ['ch%.1d%.2d' % (y for y in range(1,3), x for x in range(1,6)]
```

...because of unclosed parenthesis.

You want:

```
print(['ch{}0{}'.format(i, j) for i in range(1, 3) for j in range(1,6)])
```

**Result:**

```
['ch101', 'ch102', 'ch103', 'ch104', 'ch105', 'ch201', 'ch202', 'ch203', 'ch204', 'ch205']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
final_list=["ch{}{:02d}".format(x,y) for x in (1,2) for y in range(1,6)]
#['ch101', 'ch102', 'ch103', 'ch104', 'ch105', 
  'ch201', 'ch202', 'ch203', 'ch204', 'ch205']
```

Or, there is nothing wrong with combining what you have:

```
final_list=['ch1%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]+['ch2%.2d' % x for x in range(1,6)]
```

Comment: In reality, i will have hundreds and thousands of these: row001_column00001 to row001_column00100 to row099_column00001 to row999_column00100

Comment: So use range. A nested list comprehension does not have any inherent advantage to the way you are doing it already: two comprehensions and list addition.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `itertools.product` to produce the values.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> ['ch{}{:02}'.format(x, y) for x, y in product(range(1,3), range(1, 6))]
['ch101', 'ch102', 'ch103', 'ch104', 'ch105', 'ch201', 'ch202', 'ch203', 'ch204', 'ch205']
```